# sqlite & mono & Entity Framework - are there any open source libraries available?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, mono

I'm trying to convert my application into Mono so I can use it with Mac - but I'm not sure what's the best way to work with database. Currently i'm using EF6 - but i read few posts saying that it's not working with Mono. I googled more - and there is paid provider which seem to support what I need: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/entityframework.html - but I'm wondering if there are free alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at NHibernate?  It is quite different than EF, but close enough that it still would be in the realm of possible to port.

Comment: thanks - i will take a look at it! i heard it's rather complex though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively small database, one way is to use Typed DataSets instead of EF and serialize/deserialize them to a disk file. Normal operations can be performed against the in-memory copy and reading/writing of the disk file can be done at open/commit time. Doesn't require any database support or external libraries, and should be easily portable to Mono, because DataSets are part of the BCL since .NET Framework v 1.0.